# How do you write only certain CMSampleBuffer frames to a new movie file in AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, coreml

I'd like to perform pose analysis on user imported video, automatically producing an `AVFoundation` video output where only frames with [a detected pose](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/detecting_human_actions_in_a_live_video_feed) are a part of the result. In the [Building a Feature-Rich App for Sports Analysis](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/building_a_feature-rich_app_for_sports_analysis) sample code, analysis happens by implementing the `func cameraViewController(_ controller: CameraViewController, didReceiveBuffer buffer: CMSampleBuffer, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation)` delegate callback, such as in line 326 of `GameViewController.swift`.

Where I'm stuck is using this analysis to only keep particular frames with a pose detected. Say I've analyzed all `CMSampleBuffer` frames and classified which ones have the pose I want. How would I only those specific frames for the new video output?

The "AVFoundation Programming Guide" link is broken in Apple's documentation archive, so conceptual explanations are hard to find. Preference is for answers in Swift, though Objective-C would still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record CMSampleBuffer, you can use this code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class MovieRecorder {
    
    private var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
    
    private var assetWriterVideoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    
    private var assetWriterAudioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    
    private var videoTransform: CGAffineTransform
    
    private var videoSettings: [String: Any]

    private var audioSettings: [String: Any]

    private(set) var isRecording = false
    
    init(audioSettings: [String: Any], videoSettings: [String: Any], videoTransform: CGAffineTransform) {
        self.audioSettings = audioSettings
        self.videoSettings = videoSettings
        self.videoTransform = videoTransform
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        // Create an asset writer that records to a temporary file
        let outputFileName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(outputFileName).appendingPathExtension("MOV")
        guard let assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(url: outputFileURL, fileType: .mov) else {
            return
        }
        
        // Add an audio input
        let assetWriterAudioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
        assetWriterAudioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        assetWriter.add(assetWriterAudioInput)
        
        // Add a video input
        let assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
        assetWriterVideoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        assetWriterVideoInput.transform = videoTransform
        assetWriter.add(assetWriterVideoInput)
        
        self.assetWriter = assetWriter
        self.assetWriterAudioInput = assetWriterAudioInput
        self.assetWriterVideoInput = assetWriterVideoInput
        
        isRecording = true
    }
    
    func stopRecording(completion: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
        guard let assetWriter = assetWriter else {
            return
        }
        
        self.isRecording = false
        self.assetWriter = nil
        
        assetWriter.finishWriting {
            completion(assetWriter.outputURL)
        }
    }
    
    func recordVideo(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        guard isRecording,
            let assetWriter = assetWriter else {
                return
        }
        
        if assetWriter.status == .unknown {
            assetWriter.startWriting()
            assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer))
        } else if assetWriter.status == .writing {
            if let input = assetWriterVideoInput,
                input.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                input.append(sampleBuffer)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func recordAudio(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        guard isRecording,
            let assetWriter = assetWriter,
            assetWriter.status == .writing,
            let input = assetWriterAudioInput,
            input.isReadyForMoreMediaData else {
                return
        }
        
        input.append(sampleBuffer)
    }
}
```